# passing pointers to nested functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, parameter-passing

I am having problems passing a pointer to a pointer(struct) through a nested function to have memory allocated or reallocated for it. I understand that when passing to a function it is passed by value, and thus only can be edited locally, but am unclear syntactically how to pass it. Important code snippets below:

```
struct courseData{
                    char name[25];   
                    int id;          
                  };

void menuSwitch(int* courseNum, struct courseData** course);
void addCourse(int* courseNum, struct courseData** course);

int main(){

     struct courseData* course = NULL;  
     int courseNum = 0;

     menuSwitch(courseNum, &course); //Edited from original post.

     return 0;
}

void menuSwitch(int* courseNum, struct courseData** course){

     addCourse(&courseNum, course)
}
```

menuSwitch is actually a case switch, which  calls function addCourse when the menu item is selected.

```
void addCourse(int* courseNum, struct courseData** course){

      if(*courseNum == 0)
                    *course = (struct courseData*) malloc(sizeof(struct courseData));
            else
                    *course = (struct courseData*) realloc(*course, (*courseNum + 1)*sizeof(struct courseData));

      *courseNum = *courseNum + 1; //Increments course count by 1

      ------code continues------
}
```

After correcting original problem, compiling results in the following errors/warnings from gcc

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:27:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘menuSwitch’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
header.h:24:6: note: expected ‘struct courseData *’ but argument is of type ‘struct courseData **’
func.c:60:6: error: conflicting types for ‘menuSwitch’
header.h:24:6: note: previous declaration of ‘menuSwitch’ was here
func.c: In function ‘menuSwitch’:
func.c:64:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘addCourse’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
header.h:26:6: note: expected ‘struct courseData *’ but argument is of type ‘struct courseData **’
```

Thank you for your help, and pardon if this is inappropriate use of the edit ability.

Comment: should be `addCourse(courseNum, course)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine except one line. In `void menuSwitch(int* courseNum, struct courseData** course)` change

```
addCourse(&courseNum, course)
```

to

```
addCourse(courseNum, course);
```

Comment: Thank you I have corrected that portion of the code, but after compiling I am recieving this errors/warning from from gcc:

Comment: It seems that at least some of your errors are not connected with posted code. I have checked the code you posted and it works. Please check this link https://ideone.com/oXhhn5

Comment: @user3450626 `header.h` declares `menuSwitch` incorrectly. It should match the definition you posted in your code above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you original suggestion fixed my issue along with some typos in my program.

Answer (score 1):

You were doing fine until you got to `menuSwitch`. That function receives `courseNum`, which is a pointer to `int`. It should then pass that same pointer `addCourse` just as it does with `course`. However, you pass *the address of* `courseNum` instead. So instead of passing an `int *` you're passing the address of a pointer to `int *`, or an `int **`. The call to `addCourse` should simply be this:

```
addCourse(courseNum, course);
```